# Remove old user permissions from all folders

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I have a lot of folders on several drives that are kept across Windows installations. For some reason they have always asked for permission to view some of these folders, so after several installs they have quite a few "Account Unknown" users attached.
I'm never going to be using any of these older Windows installations because they've been overwritten, so I'd like to clean up the permissions.

Is there a program or tool I can use to scan for old permissions? Preferably it would also remove the old permissions and fix them all up so I'm not asked for permissions on a reinstall.